# java programming

Tags: java, sorting, quicksort

hey i am unable to understand the logic and program of Quicksort...can u help...

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort

Comment: What exactly are you unable to understand? What have you tried/read so far to try to tackle this problem/task/homework/...? Or maybe it would be better if you didn't bothered yourself with this and someone simply gave you the code?

Comment: We can help, but we can't read in your mind.

Answer (score 2):

Accordingly to the link posted by Adam, this image will help you:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Here's a step-by-step walkthrough of quicksort.

http://pages.stern.nyu.edu/~panos/java/Quicksort/